# Uninstall Windows Defender in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, uninstall, windows-defender

Can Windows Defender be permanently uninstalled/removed from my current Windows 7 installation, it can't be done through the Add/Remove Programs Wizard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do not think it is possible to completly remove without the aid of a tool such as [Vlite](http://www.vlite.net/about.html).

However, your best bet is to go in to "Computer Management" then "Services" and set the Windows Defender service to disabled.

Answer (score 2):

Not that I know of, but you could stop it bothering you by setting the service to disabled.

Answer (score 2):

You can also go into the Windows Defender GUI an uncheck the option "Use Windows Defender".

Answer (score 1):

Open the RUN dialog box (windows + R key) and type "services.msc".

You can disable the windows Defender and many other services from there and also the Firewall.

Answer (score 1):

There is a portable application entitled [Windows Defender Uninstaller](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/download/did/1984/).

- Download it from the link above.
- Run it.
- Click the button to uninstall Defender.
- The lower pane will show what’s being deleted and if there are any errors.

**However:**

Please read this article entitled ["How To Disable, Uninstall or Remove Windows Defender"](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-disable-uninstall-or-remove-windows-defender-in-vista/) to gain greater insight to the above actions including firstly disabling Windows Defender (best practice) and also *How To Manually Remove it* (if you feel that this is more appropriate), before attempting the above.

Comment: Best method until now. I have tested the others, as I have done with many tutorials thorugh the web, and this is the one that seems to work for me. Well... I have not tested the VLite program, but I don't want to install anything on my Windows if a simple executable program does the job OK automatically in just a few seconds plus one reboot.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez Glad to be of assistance :)

Answer (score 0):

See [How To Uninstall, Disable, and Remove Windows Defender. Also, How Turn it Off](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15788/how-to-uninstall-disable-and-remove-windows-defender.-also-how-turn-it-off/).